# obtain a hidden value from cxLookupComboBox1 for a query

Tags: delphi, devexpress

My cxLookupComboBox1 gets two values from a datasource: DEPT_ID and DEPARTMENT (Only the DEPARTMENT name is visible in the cxLookupComboBox1).

However, I need the DEPT_ID to pass as a parameter for my insert query. How can I obtain this value from the cxLookupComboBox1 ???

Right now I must display the DEPT_ID in the cxLookupComboBox1 so I can use it for the query :

```
DataModule2.INS_UPO_ENOTA.Params.ParamByName('a1').Value := cxLookupComboBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Don't get it from the user interface (ie cxLookupComboBox1) but get it from the underlying dataset.

Comment: @whosrdaddy  If the SynchMode property in Properties|ListOptions is set to true..

Comment: or by index number ?